# What is the use case of the generic ViewMasterPage<T>?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

In ASP.NET MVC there are generic master views (`ViewMaserPage<T>`). But what is the purpose of them? As I see it, generic argument of master view and "slave" view must be equal and this constraints me to using the same model for all my views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have abstract BaseViewModel which contain for example properties Title, Description, Keywords, ..., and all other view model classes inherits from BaseViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use a base type for your model as the generic argument for your master page.